# Fonts rejected by sanitizer in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts

I am using react and getting font issues on my page. Before it was working but now I am getting the below error in the console.

I have tried some comments like `npm audit --force` (something like this not remembers).

Even my images also do not display what I have added from CSS.

> downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Satoshi-Bold"
> style:normal weight:700 stretch:100 src index:2) source:
> http://localhost:3000/public/fonts/Satoshi-Bold.ttf downloadable font:
> rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Satoshi-Medium" style:normal
> weight:500 stretch:100 src index:2) source:
> http://localhost:3000/public/fonts/Satoshi-Medium.ttf

I am using the below font code in css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Satoshi-Medium';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Satoshi-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/public/fonts/Satoshi-Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('/public/fonts/Satoshi-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Satoshi-Bold';
    src: url('/public/fonts/Satoshi-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/public/fonts/Satoshi-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('/public/fonts/Satoshi-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This might sound stupid but have you tried changing the single quotes in your URLs to double quotes? I think FF is weird about single quotes. You could also try adding `..` before `/public/`  but I don't know what your folder structure looks like.

Comment: @AStombaugh, Yes, The issue is with the path. I have removed the /public and it's started working

Comment: awesome! Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had these same errors loading Google fonts, and solved it by using `@import` instead of `@font-face`.:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&display=swap');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you don't have Google font then how can you use that font?

Comment: @NarenVerma Google fonts are free for anyone, so you can use a Google font just by adding it to your site.  

Start by visiting https://fonts.google.com/ and choosing a font you'd like on your site. Beside each font sample is an option to select that style, and when you click it Google will generate the code you need to make it work on your own website.  You just add the code to the <head> section of your page.  

(If you don't see it, look at the top right for the "Hide selected families" icon, which shows or hides the sidebar with the code.)